# Finding a global solution for the IVP

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

im trying to find the global solution for the following IVP. In general, I know how to check if theres a global solution but I dont know how to calculate it.

**PROBLEM:**

The IVP is $\dot x = t^{2}|x|^{2/3}$, $x(t_{0})=x_{0}$.

Let $(t_{0},x_{0})=(1,1)$. **How can I build a global solution?** And whats the process to see if it is locally unique or globally unique?

Any help would be incredibly appreciated, thanks so much.

My only work in this problem was to find the explicit solution for the IVP(the easy part)

$\int _{1}^{t} \frac{\dot x }{|x|^{2/3}} = \int _{1}^{t} t^{2}dt$, now changing variables and integrating we get to:

$3|x(t)|^{1/3} - 3 = \frac{t^{3}}{3} -\frac{1}{3}$

$|x(t)|= (\frac{t^{3}}{9}+\frac{8}{9})^{3}$

Comment: Separate variables

Comment: Yeah, but once I solve it how do I build the global solution D:

Comment: And well, I know it must have a global solution cause $\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}$ is bounded

Comment: You should first show us how you solved it. Efforts by the ones that ask is highly appreciated here.

Comment: But my problem is that I dont know how to solve that, :/. I could show how I got to the explicit solution but I havent done any other work cause I dont know what Im suppose to do D:

Comment: So, what's your solution?

Comment: I posted it sir :)

Comment: I got $+\frac 89$ instead of $-\frac 89$.

Comment: So, this solution is valid for $t\ge t_1 = -2$ (and $x_1=0$). Now, start again with the initial value $(t_1,x_1)$ and for $x\le 0$ so that $|x|^{2/3} = (-x)^{2/3}$.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see another way than extending the function on $(-\infty,-2)$ by zero. Then you have your global solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$
x(t) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac 1{9^3}(t^3+8)^3 &\text{for $t\ge-2$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is a global solution.